# Does codepen solve for responsiveness?

Tags: css, codepen, object-fit

I was struggling a lot with getting my images to fit inside their parent element. In order to ask a better StackOverflow question, I decided to makde a codepen, but when I did that, the issue was solved? it's still not solved when I run a local server though. Can anyone explain this?

Outer div:

```
.img-holder{
  opacity: .5;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80vw;
  display: block;
  max-height: 80vh;
}
```

inside image:

```
  img {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: relative;
  max-height: 80vh;
}
```

http://codepen.io/evejweinberg/pen/vgRNWR

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://codepen.io/justdan/pen/XpEmOp

Comment: One difference could be that CodePen is using standards mode and your standalone HTML page is using Quirks...

Comment: @DanielD - two things that are un-ideal about your version are 1) images are stretched and 2) images go beyond the height of the tan  canvas.